# Why won't my boolean work correctly?

Tags: etoolbox

Sorry for the very open question title, but I can't really figure out what is wrong exactly. I wanted to save a little time when writing semantic types, which are usually subscript but are often recursive, leading to types within types, like this:

D<sub><e,<s,t>></sub>

The easiest solution seemed to me to use a boolean which checks whether I am within Type Brackets (<>) already; if so, \type would not use \textsubscript, if not, \type would set the boolean to true and use \textsubscript; the last command in \type would set the boolean to false if it had been false when the command was called. This is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{intype}
\newcommand{\type}[1]{\ifbool{intype}{$\langle$#1$\rangle$}{\setbool{intype}{true}\textsubscript{$\langle$#1$\rangle$}}\setbool{intype}{false}}

\begin{document}
D\type{\type{$\tau$,\type{$s,t$}},\type{$\tau$,\type{$s$,$t$}}}
\end{document}
```

The expected output is D<sub><<τ,<s,t>>,<τ,<s,t>></sub>.

The output I get is D<sub><<τ,<s,t>>,<sub><τ,<s,t>></sub>.</sub>

This is really confusing - If my solution doesn't work, why isn't the <s,t> bit in the first pair of brackets lower than the τ?

<sub>Sorry for that long line of code btw, as far as I can tell, adding spaces or line breaks produces unwanted spaces in the output.</sub>

Comment: A Warm Welcome to TeX.SE! Nice MWE :)

Comment: Thanks! What did you like about it?

Comment: For starters there _was_ a MWE.  Beyond that you have stated your question clearly.  I don't think that my first question was this clear, and I most likely did not have a proper MWE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are setting it false too soon, but you can just use the grouping to set it back automatically:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{intype}
\newcommand{\type}[1]{%
  \ifbool{intype}%
  {$\langle$#1$\rangle$}%
  {\textsubscript{\setbool{intype}{true}$\langle$#1$\rangle$}}%
  }

\begin{document}
D\type{\type{$\tau$,\type{$s,t$}},\type{$\tau$,\type{$s$,$t$}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not ownly does that work, but you managed to split up the macro without creating any spaces. Is that on account of the %s? Also, ***why*** does it work? I don't see you ever setting the boolean back to false. And I thought I was setting it to false right at the end of the macro, so how can it have been too early? (This is not meant to critizise your answer, it is exactly what I needed, so feel free to ignore these questions.)

Comment: yes an end of line is a space but if you comment it out, it isn't there:-) setbool is a local setting so the value reverts to what it was at the end of the subscript just like the font `{\bfseries xxx} yyy` reverting back from bold at the `}` you don't need to explicitly set it back. In your code you had the setting to false _after_ the ifbool test so you were always setting it to false even if it was true at the start of the macro.  so it would also have worked to have moved one the `}` here `}}\setbool` to the end, but using grouping is more the tex way.

Comment: I checked that thrice :( Now I see it, there's a } too many after the langlerangle. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The boolean is set to false in the wrong place.

Here's a different implementation, based on grouping, that avoids code repetition. Since `\textsubscript` typesets its argument in a group, the “outer” definition of `\type` will be restored as soon as the subscript has been typeset.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\type}[1]{%
  \textsubscript{\let\type\innertype\innertype{#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\innertype}[1]{$\langle$#1$\rangle$}

\begin{document}
D\type{\type{$\tau$,\type{$s,t$}},\type{$\tau$,\type{$s$,$t$}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty sweet. I always thought the \let command was particularly useless. I seem to have been particularly wrong.

Comment: @thisismynamenow It takes some time (and coding) to appreciate the power of `\let`.